# Is there a plug-in or way to use a tag selection bar like Dreamweaver

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I am trying to start doing my html/css/js development work in Sublime Text 2. I have been using Dreamweaver for many years and have come to rely on the tag selection bar in dreamweaver that appears at the bottom of the code view screen. it looks like this:

[screenshot of tag selection bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfLy2.png)

This allows me to navigate up and down complex table-based layouts in email templates and remove/insert block of html very quickly. Is there a plug-in or way to view the DOM like this in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: I don't believe there is..

Answer (score 0):

Within the Selection/Expand Selection to Tag menu item, you can hit the associated key binding several times to increase what's selected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the "Expand Selection to Tag" option in the Selection menu and did not get anything. Since I'm new to Sublime text 2, I didn't really understand what you meant when you wrote "hit the associated key binding". Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: "Key Bindings" preferences file that holds hotkeys, key combinations, shortcuts. Here, CONTROL SHIFT A.